# WCF hosted on IIS 7 cannot verify security of the message

Tags: wcf, ssl, iis-7, self-signed

I've a WCF service hosted on IIS 7 which uses a self-signed certificated to provide HTTPS connection.

The server is located in US but the client that consumes it are in the middle east. In order the clients to be able to use the service I had to change the server's time and Timezone to the country that the clients are. 
This configuration was working (for almost a year now) but from 2 days ago the some of the clients stop working and getting the following error:

> An error occurred when verifying security for the message.

If I change the server time to one hour before the not working clients these clients will be able to use the service but the previously working ones stop working and receiving the same error.

Does anybody know how can I fix this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's two sides you can tackle this from: if you have AppFabric or something similar installed in your IIS, you can start writing trace files for your service. That should give you a pretty good picture of *what* went wrong on the server side.

On the client side, without touching the server, you may want to check if you can get more specific errors than just "something with security didn't work" that .NET likes to give. Try to write a console application calling your service and check on the SSL errors there.

```
namespace ServiceTestConsole
{
  using System;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Net.Security;
  using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

  internal class Program
  {
    internal static void Main()
    {
      ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertificate;

      // add a service reference and call your service here

      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslpolicyerrors)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("SSL Policy Error(s): " + sslpolicyerrors);

      return true;
    }
  }
}
```